# Best way to rotate Magento logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, logrotate, magento

We have a lot of sites on Magento and the logs are getting gigantic, so I'm wondering if the best way is to use a cron script to rotate them or logrotate. I want to avoid making file copies as it junks up the folder and makes it hard to navigate, so ideally I would want to have only log lines going back two weeks in one file for each domain. Is this possible or is it better to rotate by file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the man pages for logrotate, as well as some of the active uses in the system.  It has  a lot of flexibility including rotation based on size, number of cycles to keep, etc.  It will do what you want.

Check it out.